# Patching react component used from a node package

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have several React components from my design library that are extensively used in my React app. Throughout the app, there are numerous instances of: `import { Text, Button, xyz & more } from 'my-awesome-design-library'`

Now, I want to extend the functionality of **Text** and **Button** components and introduce some functionality based on certain global state in Redux. To achieve this, I can create wrapper components like **MagicText** and **MagicButton**, defined in `src/MagicModule`.

At this point, I would need to manually update all occurrences of the components' imports. However, using a simple find and replace won't work because some of the imports may include additional named imports (like "xyz & more" as mentioned above).

- works for `import { Text } from 'my-awesome-design-library'`
- does not work `import { Text, List, Heading } from 'my-awesome-design-library'`

Keeping this as a last resort, I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve this, such as monkey patching. So, my question is: is there a way to configure my app to read from `src/components/MagicModule` when importing from `my-awesome-design-library`?

Comment: Not sure if there is a magic way to patch but I'd use https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports blacklisting all the imports of `Text` and `Button` from `my-awesome-design-library` and just fixing all the errors IDE/linter shows after that.